# Make particular View visible when comment section start

Tags: react-native, view, hide, visible

In this code there is description part, comments section and one comment TextInput.
 So I want to make TextInput View visible when comment section View start that is when user will scroll to comment section and TextInput View will be hidden when when the user is on description part.

For this i think we need to find the height of description View and if it crosses to that height then the comment TextInput View will be visible. but i am not sure with it.
suggest if anyone know the solution.

```
renderCommentInput(){
 return(
  <View>
   <TextInput/>
  </View>
 );
}   

render() {
 return(
 <Container>
   <ScrollView>
     <View>
      <Text>{this.state.description}</Text>
     </View>
     <View>
     // The code to print comments in map
     </View>
    </ScrollView>
    {this.renderCommentInput()}
  </Container>
 );
}
```